# number of ways to put N labelled balls in N labelled boxes so that labels don't match?

Tags: combinatorics

I have N distinct balls labelled 1 to N, and associated N boxes labelled 1 to N. How many different ways can I place all balls into the boxes (one ball per box) so that there is no ball-box label matching, i.e. ball $i$ is not in box $i$, for all $i=1,...,N$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is known as derangement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 1):

You want to count a special kind of permutation called derrangement. The number of derrangements on $N$ objects is sometimes denoted $!N$.

Perhaps the easiest way to calculate them is with the following recursion:

$!N=(N-1)(!(N-1)+!(N-2))$